# Copy text and paste in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I would like to copy a text from a webpage and paste it in another field on the same web page.

Here is what I've tried so far without success

This is my code:

```
Browser("Candidate").Page("Candidate").WebEdit("ctl00$Main$Tabs").GetROProperty + micCtrlDwn + "a" + micCtrlUp
Browser("Candidate").Page("Candidate").WebEdit("ctl00$Main$Tabs").GetROProperty + micCtrlDwn + "c" + micCtrlUp
Browser("Candidate").Page("Candidate").WebEdit("ctl00$Main$TabsCPe_3").Click
Browser("Candidate").Page("Candidate").WebEdit("ctl00$Main$TabsCPe_3").GetROProperty + micCtrlDwn + "v" + micCtrlUp
```

It clicks on the field i need it to copy the text from but does not select all the text and copy it to the defined destination.

[Object properties for feild1 after entering text manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baamn.png)

[feild1 object spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGVeK.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just fetch the value from field1, store it in a variable and set that value to field2 as shown below:

```
Dim strValue
'fetch the value from field1 and store it in a variable
strValue = Browser("Candidate").Page("Candidate").WebEdit("ctl00$Main$Tabs").getRoProperty("value")

'set that value to field2
Browser("Candidate").Page("Candidate").WebEdit("ctl00$Main$TabsCPe_3").set strValue
```

Comment: The value in field1 is not set and changes constantly. That's why I wanted to simulate the copy and paste action.

Comment: Whatever the value may be, getroproperty("text") fetches the run-time value of the property-"text" of that field. It means, during the runtime, whatever value/text is in field1, that will be fetched and stored in variable

Comment: @Nova Did you try this code? If yes, are you getting any error or is the code getting executed without doing anything? Try to print the value fetched and see if the value being fetched is correct or not. If not, check if there is any other property of field1 that stores the field1 value using object spy.

Comment: The code executed without any errors but did nothing. Tried printing the value but no value fetched it would appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: Enter some value in that field1 manually and perform spy on that field. Post the screenshot of the object spy here. May be the field value is contained in some other property of that field.

Comment: Image added to the question. Thanks

Comment: We need the object Spy image, not the OR's image. Like this one: http://www.softwaretestinggenius.com/photos/qtp11new.JPG It displays the property-value pairs for an object. Expand the spy window properly so that we are able to see all the property-value pairs, take the screenshot and post here

Comment: The image has been added to the question

Comment: What is the text which you want to copy? Is it "Test" at this moment? I have updated the code. Re-run it. I have just changed the property name from "text" to "value"

Comment: Glad that worked. Don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Yes. It will work everytime. It will just fetch the RUNTIME value from field1 and set it to field2

Comment: Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem.. :)